# How do you use foldl in erlang on a list of integers to return the maximum integer?

Tags: erlang, max, anonymous-function, fold

I would like to use the below Erlang code to get the highest integer in a list of integers but for some reason always end up getting the last integer in the list. Any help?

Solution example -> `test:max([2,8,5,6]).` should return 8 but with this code it returns 6.

```
-spec max(L) -> M when
  L::[integer()],
  M::integer().

max([H | T]) ->
F = fun(L, Acc) -> max([L]) end,
lists:foldl(F, H, T).
```

Answer (score 6):

Your function `F` should return the max of `L` and `Acc`. You can use the builtin `max/2` function for that:

```
...
F = fun(L, Acc) -> max(L, Acc) end.
...
```

Test:

```
1> F = fun(L, Acc) -> max(L, Acc) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.12.52032458>
2> [H | T] = [2, 8, 5, 6].
[2,8,5,6]
3> lists:foldl(F, H, T).
8
```

Answer (score 1):

What you return in your function `F` will be the new value of `Acc`, and eventually the value `lists:foldl/3` will return.

What you may want to do is do comparison inside `F` and check if `Acc` is greater than the current value. You don't need to recurse `max/1` since you're iterating the list in `lists:foldl/3` anyway.

Let me know if you need the actual code right away, but I would recommend figuring it out yourself. It's more fun for you that way.